# Python operators '/' vs. '//'

Tags: python-3.x, operators

I encountered the use of the `//` operator in place of `/` in a Python tutorial I was going through. What is the difference between the `/` and `//` operator in Python?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Python 3.0 and above, check in your terminal.

a) `/` operator, aka classic division

```
>>> 5/2
2.5
```

b) `//` operator, aka floor division

```
>>> 5//2
2
```

#### Reference

*[9.9. operator — Standard operators as functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.div)*